# How to modify a method in a JAR without the source code?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file and need to modify one of the methods inside of it. The jar is for computer automation, typing and using the mouse. There are a lot of higher level methods (e.g. search the screen for an 'X' and if found, mouse moves to the X and left clicks on it) that rely on functions such as mousemove, mouseclick. The mouse class is final and I don't have access to the source code though I can see it decompiled in Intellj.

Is there a way to modify / replace these functions? Like for example, instead of the mousepress doing a left button down press, it would press the 'k' key instead. And still be able to use the rest of the higher level functions in the jar (eg. mouse would move to the 'X' and then the 'k' button would be pressed).

Comment: You can copy the class to another java file, compile it and replace the compiled file in the JAR(a JAR file is a ZIP file).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the class and override the method if the API allows you.

Comment: "The mouse class is final" so nope